Error in MS Excel after filling XLSX form with PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet
I am using the PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet package to fill the fields of a SEPA.xlsx form. The fields are filled successfully, but when the filled form is saved to a new file, opening that file in MS Excel results in an error indicating that something is wrong with the file and it attempts to repair it.
Here is short example code:
// Reading the file:
$reader = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$reader->setReadDataOnly(false);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('SEPA.xlsx');
$currentTab = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName('CarrierSchedule');

// Filling cells:
$currentTab->getCell('B30')->setValue('Product name');

// Saving file:
$writer = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($this->spreadsheet);
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$writer->save('my_file.xlsx');

// Closing file:
$spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($spreadsheet);

I have tried:

different settings using reader PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader and writer PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer
using empty strings for cells when data is missing
not setting any values for cells when data is missing
cloning data into new worksheet and then filling.

The problem/bug: after filling xlsx form and saving it to new file using MS Excel on Mac shows error: "We found a problem with some content in 'my_file.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.".
Expected behavior: the new file opens using MS Excel without errors.

Does it behave differently, when you take out that one line that tries to set the new cell content?

@C3roe the same error when skipping the filling cells part.
